# Why are some html forms losing their values when transferring pages? PHP

Tags: php, forms

Let's just say I have a form that takes me to welcome.php

and in **index.php** I'll have:

```javascript
document.form01.vccv.value="1"; //This is a checked checkbox that is on and will alert 1 when prompted its value.
document.form01.submit();
```

When arriving to welcome.php, their is no POST variable assigned to "vccv" so it never records its way to the file.

In **welcome.php** I will receive and assign the POST values like so:

```php
foreach($_POST as $varname=>$value)
  $formvars[$varname]=str_replace('"',"''",$value);
```

The worst part is this is only happening in some instances. It usually works fine.

What started this issue is we recently updated our php version from 5.3 to 5.6. Has anyone ever heard of forms losing their values?

Minimal reproductible example:

**index.php**

```javascript
alert(document.form01.vccv.value) // this returns 1 every time since it is checked. 
form01.submit; // this sends me to welcome.php
```

**welcome.php**

```php
print_r($_POST); // returns all post variable to which vccv sometimes does not show up.
```

This is all of the code related to this issue. It sometimes does not carry over. The transition from php version 5.3 to 5.6 is the cause of this issue.

Comment: Instead of just describing what you expect the code to be doing, can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  Now is also a good time to start using your browser's debugging tools to narrow down where the problem is occurring, specifically observing the POST request being made to see what data it contains and narrow down is the problem is in the code which makes the request or the code which receives the request.

Comment: PHP 5.6 reached end of life in _2018_ and has received _no security updates in 5 years_. At this point PHP 7 is also EOL, and even 8.0 is in "security only" updates. If you're upgrading PHP you should strongly consider jumping straight to 8.2.

Comment: "only happening in some instances" - please share more details about this. Which of these "instances" are working, which are not, what's the difference between them?

Comment: *"This is all of the code related to this issue."* - No, it isn't.  Please carefully read the [mcve] page again.  Currently you're asking us to assume that your code must be correct and to provide you with any potential problems in PHP itself which would cause this.  This approach won't get you far.

Comment: I wish we could jump to a higher version of php, but it hasn't been done because there is a very hefty amount of 'mysql_' calls instead of 'mysqli_' that all need to be changed

Comment: look, these pages in actuality are several thousands of lines long. All I can do is meet in the middle where the problem is. In javascript, it is clear that I have the field 'vccv' that is set to one. If it didn't exist, then it wouldn't be able to alert it. It submits in the next line. And in the next file print_r($_POST ) does not include it. What am I missing?

Comment: I am asking whether anyone knows the difference between php version 5.3 to 5.6. It is a very specific question regarding form handling between these versions that I was unable to find online. That is why I am here.

Comment: @Hunter the most plausible cause is that *vccv* is not checked (although its value is set to "1") and thus not sent to the backend.

Comment: I wish it wasn't checked

Comment: @Hunter an unchecked checkbox is never sent to the backend, regardless of its value.
For this, sometimes, when the backend is PHP, an hidden input with a default value and with same name of the chekbox is placed before the checkbox. When the checkbox is not checked then PHP will receive the value of the hidden input.

Comment: My condolences for having to maintain such a crappy code! 
I am currently also stuck with inherited crappy code originally written in php5.2 However we bumped it up by now to 7.4 and it is really worth the hassle if you have to maintain it longer than the next 8 months. Upgrade and refactor, it will make you day better.

Comment: Look at all the release notes: https://www.php.net/releases/5_4_0.php and following

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when updating our php version from 5.3 to 5.6, The .ini variable "Max_Post_variables" was set or changed back to the default (1000). This was causing some variables to not carry over to the next page within files with large amounts of user made variables.